# Friends scores not included in Facebook Graph API Scores

Tags: ruby, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to implement Scores for my Facebook Game (Flash Game with Ruby/Sinatra Backend). It actually works without errors, but the problem is, that only my own Score is shown.
A friend has added and allowed the app all it requests and he has the same problem. Only his score is shown, but not mine.

I'm requesting the Scores via the following code:

```
@client = Mogli::Client.new(session[:at])
@scores = @client.get_and_map("/#{ENV["FACEBOOK_APP_ID"]}/scores")
```

As I said, the method returns the correct answer but it just contains the score for the user and not for his friends. In the documentation it says that the call will return all scores for the game.

I tried the call in the FB Graph Debugger Console and it returned the same result there. Just my score. I tried implementing it on my own with Net::HTTP.get, but I got the same results.

Did anyone try the Scores before and can give me a hint on what I'm doing wrong?

I tried all access_tokens by the way and obviously it only returns anything with the user_access_token (since it says so in the documentation).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks, LetzFlow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually they might have changed the documentation on you. As found on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/application/ in the Connections section of the page, it currently says:

> **scores**
>
> Scores for the user and their friends.

.

Further reading at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/application/#scores indicates you need to use a valid user access token to get their score and scores of their friends.  So this further says not everyones score is going to come back, only the scores of the user and their friends who also have authenticated your game app.

If you're not getting these results, then you can file a bug at http://developers.facebook.com/bugs.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that's exactly what I tried to do. I'm using a valid user access token and should get the scores from me and my friend. But we both only get our own.

Comment: Then it's a bug.  You should report it to developers.facebook.com/bugs (or see if there's already one logged).

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your friend has set his visibility of the app to "Friends" and not "Only Me". The scores API will filter any friends who have set visibilty to "Only Me".